# Imagewriter executes only last call

Tags: image, image-processing, avisynth

I have 3 imagewriter, each of it save a different frame from avi to a path. But, it is executed only the last imagewriter, so I received in test3 folder frame 4, with name: 000004.jpg
Why the first 2 imagewriter aren't executed? Can I execute all imagewriter in other way? 
Even if I change the order of those, only the last imagewriter is executed.
The code is:

```
clip=DirectshowSource("D:\images\ball-flame.avi").ConvertToRGB32()
imagewriter(clip,"D:\images\test1\",start=1,end=1,type="jpg") 
imagewriter(clip,"D:\images\test2\",start=2,end=2,type="jpg") 
imagewriter(clip,"D:\images\test3\",start=4,end=4,type="jpg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous clips are discarded because they aren't used by anything in the video pipeline. I forgot most of AviSynth I knew though so here's a workaround which may not be the best:

```
StackVertical(\
    imagewriter(clip,"D:\images\test1\",start=1,end=1,type="jpg").crop(0,0, 16,16),\
    imagewriter(clip,"D:\images\test1\",start=2,end=2,type="jpg").crop(0,0, 16,16),\
    imagewriter(clip,"D:\images\test1\",start=4,end=4,type="jpg").crop(0,0, 16,16))
```

Comment: Hello wOxxOm.Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately with this one, I can't save any of the images...

Comment: Ok. You open your video with DirectshowSource function? And what is your video extension? You use .ConvertToRGB32()?

Comment: Ah, sorry, `clip` line should be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much, wOxxOm! It worked. Have you any idea if it is possible to use a for or a while loop in order to avoid 3 imagewriters to be written? I already tried to use a for and a while outside the StackVertical but the behaviour that it has is the same as the behaviour without StackVertical (it writes only the last imagewriter). Thank you!